# Converting JSONArray to String in javascript to send to java

Tags: java, javascript, json, cordova

I am working with an android app that uses phonegap. The java calls some HTML that displays a web page and the HTML uses javascript for functions. Now in the javascript I make a JSON call using parameters from the HTML. The problem is I need to send this JSONArray back to the Java class. However, when I use

```
JavaActivity.parseJson(jsonArray.toString());
```

(where jsonArray is the JSONArray and parseJson is the method in the java activity)

the string that it sends looks something like this:

```
[{Object:Object}, {Object:Object}, {Object:Object}, .....]
```

What am I doing wrong or is there another way to convert this String, or just send the JSONArray directly?

Comment: The things in your jsonArray are apparently objects. The default implementation of Object.toString is `"{Object:Object}"`. What sort of things are in the jsonArray?

Comment: Can you show us the javascript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming jsonArray holds all the data you want to send to Java do:

```
var jString = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
```

Now 'jString' is the json encoded string representation of your array.